# Pluralization in Blazor apps

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, localization, blazor

I tried to add `PO` files to my Blazor WASM app (.NET 8 / ASPNET Core 8), but I could not succeed.
I followed [AspNetCore docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/portable-object-localization?view=aspnetcore-8.0#pluralization) which mentions `OrchardCore.Localization.Core` package, but as soon as I installed it to WASM app, it started showing errors:

```
0>Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(491,5): Error NETSDK1082 : There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.
0>------- Finished building project: BlazorApp1. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0
```

Anyway. I'm just asking if any package exists that may support pluralization in Blazor webassembly app.
If not, how can I tackle pluralization, as I could not find any good examples on the web.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer?tab=readme-ov-file#pluralize

Comment: It seems like quite a few issues exist with localization using humanizer: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+localize and I wouldn't like to add this large package to lightweight project

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you do not want to use large package like Humanizer for lightweight project you could try using the custom method. below are the sample:

1)Create a pluralization service:

```
public static class PluralizationService
{
    public static string Pluralize(int count, string singular, string plural)
    {
        return count == 1 ? singular : plural;
    }
}
```

2)Create `.resx` Files for Localization `Resources.resx` and `Resources.es.resx`

3)Apply Pluralization in Your Components:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<MyComponent> Localizer

<h1>@GetPluralizedItemsCount(itemCount)</h1>

@code {
    private int itemCount = 5;

    private string GetPluralizedItemsCount(int count)
    {
        var singular = Localizer["ItemOne"];
        var plural = Localizer["ItemOther", count];
        return PluralizationService.Pluralize(count, singular, plural);
    }
}
```